# How to better "locking" my API while asynchronously serializing this API datas?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, serialization

I'll try my best to sum up my issue.

I have a library project which manipulate 2 `Dictionary`.

```
Dictionary<ILottery, ICachedLotteryStats>? _lotteryCollection;
Dictionary<Type, List<IToStatsConverter>>? _converters;
```

To persist those datas, I chose to use `Text.Json` serialization. I called this `Save` and `Load`.
I use an `interface` API to do so.

I now want to make the call to this serialization asynchronous. Since I don't want that 2 asynchronous operation might happen at the same time, I guarded `Save` and `Load` under a `SemaphoreSlim`.

```
static readonly SemaphoreSlim _lotoSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
```

```
//Helper methods
public static async Task<TValue> GetValueAsync<TValue>(string json)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
    {
        return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<TValue>(stream, Options);
    }
}

public static async Task<string> GetJsonAsync<TValue>(TValue value)
{
    string json = string.Empty;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(stream, value, Options);
        stream.Position = 0;
        using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}


public static async Task<bool> LoadAsync(string saveFile)
{
    await _lotoSemaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        string[] json = await File.ReadAllLinesAsync(saveFile);
     
        var lotoCol = await 
          GetValueAsync<Dictionary<ILottery, ICachedLotteryStats>>(json.First());
        //Load my first Dictionary
        if (lotoCol != null) _lotteryCollection = lotoCol; else { return false; }

        var convs = await 
          GetValueAsync<Dictionary<Type, List<IToStatsConverter>>>(json.Last());
        //Load my second Dictionary
        if (convs != null) { _converters = convs; return true; }
        
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        _lotoSemaphore.Release();
    }
}

public static async Task<bool> SaveAsync(string saveFile)
{
    await _lotoSemaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {                
        //Serialize my 2 Dictionary as Json strings
        string[] jsonLines =
        {
            await GetJsonAsync(_lotteryCollection),
            await GetJsonAsync(_converters)
        };

        await File.WriteAllLinesAsync(saveFile, jsonLines);

        return true;                
    }
    finally
    {
        _lotoSemaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

To illustrate, here is how I call my library from another console project :

```
// Testing 2 consecutive asynchronous call of LoadAsync(), 
// to look if Semaphore correctly guard them.
Loto_API.API.LoadAsync();
Loto_API.API.LoadAsync();

// Testing another API method that manipulate my Dictionary while Loading them
Loto_API.API.AddSources(statsFiles, true);

//Also testing 2 asynchronous saving and loading calls.
Loto_API.API.SaveAsync();
Loto_API.API.LoadAsync();
```

---

But now come my issue. My serialization is now asynchronous, guarded under a semaphore, but the rest of my API could also manipulate my 2 `Dictionary` while I might perform an asynchronous serialization of them !

I explored some solution to this

- Guard my 2 `Dictionary` under the same Semaphore ? No because `Save` and `Load`, of course, also access those `Dictionary` to serialize them ! So couldn't use the already acquired semaphore to guard them...
- Use another asynchronous API version that will guard all API call under the Semaphore, and somehow track if it is called or not by `Save` or `Load` to bypass the semaphore then ? Seems to be an overkill, bad, solution.

What would be a better way to ensure that any of my API calls will wait for any potentially serialization (`Save`, `Load`) to finish is they ever be on the way ?
Thank you.

EDITED along @Theodor Zoulias advises.

Comment: Some of the best multithreading is when you don't need to lock.  Try to avoid sharing state between threads if possible.

Comment: `async` isn't the problem here. Any multi-threading would also cause this problem.

Comment: It's not clear what the `_lotoSemaphore` is intended to protect. Is it protecting the access to the `saveFile`? If yes, why there is only one `SemaphoreSlim`, assuming that the `saveFile` can be many different files? It doesn't help that in the usage example you call the `LoadAsync` and `SaveAsync` without passing any argument, while these two methods have a required `string saveFile` parameter. It might be also helpful to show an example of how you manipulate the two dictionaries from elsewhere. You could also remove the one dictionary from the question, in case only one is enough as a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Let remove this semaphore and just use `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` instead of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` - it's designed for thread safety. Problem solved.
For know more, let read [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=net-6.0).

Comment: I wasn't aware of this version of Dictionary ! Thanks for mentioning them, I'll look upon and test them. From what I quickly read *"ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue> uses fine-grained locking to ensure thread safety."*. So yeah surely way better than my semaphore lock I guess ;)